# Check whether Image successfully downloaded or failed

Tags: android, image, caching

I am using [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) as image loader library in my application. The application will load image from first address (URL1) but if it is failed it will try to download to second address (URL2), is it possible to check download status from picasso library wheter image successfully downloaded or not, so If I failed download image from URL1 I can try to load image from URL2.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interface **Target** in library. You can find it [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html#onSuccess%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29). It has following 2 methods.

```
void onError()
```

Callback indicating the image could not be successfully loaded.

```
void onSuccess(android.graphics.Bitmap bitmap)
```

Callback when an image has been successfully loaded.

Try to implement those in your project.